# Save pointer's memory address

Tags: c, unix, pointers, malloc

I have to implement a function that returns the memory address of a pointer when I allocate it with `malloc()`. I know that `malloc(value)` allocates an area on the heap which is of size `value`.

I know how to implement the code for printing the memory address of that pointer:

```
    void *s = malloc (size)
    printf("%p\n",s);
```

My question is, how can I save the value printed by that code in an `int` or string (e.g. `char *`)?

Comment: What are you going to do with it?  Do  you just want the string for printing purposes?  That's just a char array like any other string.  Or are you trying to store the value of the pointer itself?  That's just `s`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Storing the value of the pointer (i.e. the memory location of some variable) in a string can be done much like you've used printf:

```
char buf[128];
void *s = malloc (size);
sprintf(buf, "%p\n",s);
```

To 'save' the value into an integer (type) you can do a simple cast:

```
void *s = malloc (size);
size_t int_value = (size_t)s;
```

Since in c you never know what your machine address pointer length is, this (technically) isn't guaranteed to work quite right; both of these methods can go wrong with wacky architectures or compilers.

Comment: Would not work for "returning" value from function since `buf` will not exist once function returns.

Comment: @Floris Yes.. but that's getting a little pedantic. Markos Horro Varela did not ask for that quality.

Comment: I thought the question started with "I have to implement a _function that returns the memory address of a pointer_ when I allocate it with malloc()." We interpreted that differently, obviously.

Comment: +1 for 'size_t'.  We're porting to a Windows 10 UWP app in VisualStudio 2015 and 'int' wasn't compiling!

Answer (score 3):

```
char buf[32] = {0}
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%p\n", s);
```

then you can print it:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already saved the value as a bit pattern in s, so I assume you mean that you simply want the text output by printf as a string. The call you want is sprintf:

```
char text[255];
sprintf(text, "%p\n", s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the pointer address returned from your function, you can declare your function to return the pointer type:

```
int* myFunc(int n) {
  int* p;
  p = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  // more stuff
  return p;
}
```

This is an alternative to the use of `sprintf` as suggested (very reasonably) by other answers.

Take your pick.

Note that on some systems an `int` would not be big enought to hold a `int*` data type - using `int*` is not only clearer but safer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sprintf() is the best option. Here you can simply take any thing inside a string.